# R condtional standard deviations values of Arima object

Tags: r, conditional-statements, deviation

Is there a similar function to sigma(object = "uGARCHfit") for an Arima object ?

Or another way to get the conditional standard deviation of an Arima object.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the conditional standard deviation of arima model?

Comment: I figured it would be a vector of the variance of my returns r_t at time t-1 unless I'm mistaken.